# Facebook share callback not calling onActivityResult

Tags: android, facebook

i can successfully share to facebook post, but cannot get any callback to know if it success or not. i try to debug it and turn out onActivityResult never get called. it's weird, because my fblogin button actually use same callbackmanager and onActivityResult is called normally.

here is my code related :

```
Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("Post TEST")
            .setContentDescription(
                    "Post test")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName))
            .build();
    if (canPresentShareDialog) {
        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }
```

and

```
    aCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        shareDialog.registerCallback(
                aCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d("Facebookshare", "Canceled");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        Log.d("Facebookshare", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
                        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
                        String alertMessage = error.getMessage();
                        showResult(title, alertMessage);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                        Log.d("Facebookshare", "Success!");
                        if (result.getPostId() != null) {
                            String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
                            String id = result.getPostId();
                            String alertMessage = getString(R.string.app_name);
                            showResult(title, alertMessage);


                        }
                    }
 });
```

my onActivityResult

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        if (mCallbackManager!=null && requestCode != RC_SIGN_IN) {
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } else   if (aCallbackManager!=null && requestCode != RC_SIGN_IN) {
            aCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
else {
            // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                    GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                    firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
                } else {
                    // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GoogleSignIn failed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // updateUI(null);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```